# ASP.NET Core - API multiple parameters

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have an AJAX call wherein the body has 3 parameters

```
  async calculateSalary() {
this.setState({ loadingCalculate: true });
const token = await authService.getAccessToken();
const requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: !token ? {} : { 'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify({id: this.state.id, absentDays: this.state.absentDays, workedDays: this.state.workedDays})
};
const response = await fetch('api/employees/' + this.state.id + '/calculate',requestOptions);
const data = await response.json();
this.setState({ loadingCalculate: false,netIncome: data });
}
```

The parameters came from a form that was written in React.js

```
<div className="form-row">

{ this.state.typeId === 1? 
<div className='form-group col-md-6'>
  <label htmlFor='inputAbsentDays4'>Absent Days: </label>
  <input type='text' className='form-control' id='inputAbsentDays4' onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} value={this.state.absentDays} name="absentDays" placeholder='Absent Days' />
</div> :
<div className='form-group col-md-6'>
  <label htmlFor='inputWorkDays4'>Worked Days: </label>
  <input type='text' className='form-control' id='inputWorkDays4' onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} value={this.state.workedDays} name="workedDays" placeholder='Worked Days' />
</div>
}
</div>
```

Now when I debug in the equivalent endpoint, only the ID parameter has value, the rest returns 0.

```
   public async Task<IActionResult> Calculate([FromBody]int id, Decimal absentDays, Decimal workedDays)
    {
            //implementation
    }
```

May I ask how can I go about having the three parameters available? Removing the ID is not possible as it is one of my required parameters. The JS code was already written that way but I am open to any suggestions.

Comment: Did you try to put [FromBody] before every parameter, not only before id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use get request , it would be simplieer, but if you still want to post you will have to create view model

```
public DaysViewModel
{
public int Id {get; set;}
public int AbsentDays {get; set;} 
public int WorkedDays {get; set;}
}
```

and fix the action

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Calculate([FromBody] DaysViewModel viewModel)
    {
            //implementation
    }
```

javascript

```
const token = await authService.getAccessToken();
const requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: !token ? {} : { 'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: { viewModel:  {id: this.state.id, absentDays: this.state.absentDays, workedDays: this.state.workedDays}}
};
const response = await fetch('api/employees/calculate',requestOptions);
```

Comment: Thank you. This works. Since API method must be POST, the use of a view model is needed.